# Set range header to */* with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am uploading a file to the Vimeo API and the docs want me to check on the upload progress by sending an empty put request with this header:

```
Content-Range: bytes */*
```

Their API then replies with the range header that indicates how much of the file is uploaded. (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#verify-the-upload)

I have a while loop that runs while the upload is going on but I can't figure out how to add the header to the PUT request.  `uploadClient` is the same `HttpClient` instance that I am uploading the file with.

```
while(!requestTask.IsCompleted)
{
    var progressRequest = await uploadClient.PutAsync(uploadLink.PathAndQuery, new StringContent(""));
    var progressResult = await progressRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("I will parse progress and output here");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

How do I add the range header in the format they want to this request?

Edit:

I tried doing it like below also but how do I add the `*` to the range and it only accepts a long?

```
while(!requestTask.IsCompleted)
{
    var progressRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uploadLink.PathAndQuery);
    progressRequestMessage.Headers.Range.Ranges.Add(new RangeItemHeaderValue(*, *));

    var progressRequest = await uploadClient.SendAsync(progressRequestMessage);
    var progressResult = await progressRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("I will parse progress and output here");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Edit:

I think I need to add it like this:

```
progressRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes */*");
```

This gives me an invalid value exception so I think there may be a different way to write `bytes */*` that works but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easy to add the header, just add it to the body content.  Couldn't find this documented though so was a pain working it out.

```
var bodyContent = new StringContent("");
bodyContent.Headers.Add("Content-Range", "bytes */*");

var progressRequest = await uploadClient.PutAsync(uploadLink.PathAndQuery, bodyContent);
var progressResult = await progressRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```